# How to take full customer export from hybris

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

How can we take full hybris customer export.
i wrote an impex to export the data but there are 2 million records in database so impex is not working.Please suggest a way.

Answer (score 1):

Impex should work, maybe it takes some time but it shouldn't failed (and if it's failing you should post the error if you want to be helped).

You have to do it by code for better perfomance, using a `flexibleSearch`.

```
String flexiString = "SELECT * from {Customer}"
FlexibleSearchQuery flexibleSearchQuery = new FlexibleSearchQuery(flexiString);
flexibleSearchQuery.setResultClassList(Arrays.asList(CustomerModel.class));

final SearchResult<CustomerModel> searchResult = flexibleSearchService.search(flexibleSearchQuery);

List<CustomerModel> results = searchResult.getResult();
if(!results.isEmpty()){
    //Iterate over CustomerModel and append what you want in a file.
}
```

There is also a old method in a manager that could be used but I don't recommend it because manager are likely to be deprecated because they use jalo classes (some class are deprecated some aren't).

```
import de.hybris.platform.jalo.user.*
import de.hybris.platform.jalo.type.*
import de.hybris.platform.core.model.user.*  

Collection<Customer> users=UserManager.getInstance().findUsers(TypeManager.getInstance().getComposedType(Customer.class),null,null,null)

for(Customer cust : users){
    //Iterate over Customer and append what you want in a file.
}
```

Comment: I am not able to do it by impex because On running the impex after sometime its giving blank page and giving error host not available.I am able to run the impex successfully in staging environment as it has less rows.Also we are using hybris5.7

Comment: Ok that's weird but it's possible I guess... Just do it by code then!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use virtualjdbc extension: https://help.hybris.com/6.3.0/hcd/8c7ec0628669101481ec9d2d8dbb3a7c.html

Also there is no limit with impex. This impex file will be smale after compression.